# How to continue bash script after mocha failure

Tags: bash, mocha.js

This is a bash script that runs some mocha tests. Essentially, it should print "one", run some tests, print "two", run some tests, and print "three".  The problem is that if there is a failed mocha test, the script stops.  In this case, never printing "three".  I've tried appending `|| true` to the end of the mocha command, but that has no affect. I've also tried running mocha through `bash -c`, also with no affect.  How can I ensure that the script continues, even if mocha exits abnormally?

```
#!/bin/bash

baseDir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

echo "one"

${baseDir}/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha \
    --require ts-node/register \
    --reporter mocha-multi-reporters \
    --reporter-options configFile=${baseDir}/.mocha/config.json \
    "${baseDir}/Functional-tests/tests-that-pass.ts"

echo "two"  

${baseDir}/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha \
    --require ts-node/register \
    --reporter mocha-multi-reporters \
    --reporter-options configFile=${baseDir}/.mocha/config.json \
    "${baseDir}/Functional-tests/tests-that-fail.ts"

echo "three"
```

Comment: I don't know mocha, but could you did not say how the bash script you posted is actually executed. Could it be that it is run via `bash -e _scriptname_`? You could initially output `echo $-` and check whether it contains the letter _e_.

Comment: Thank you very much @user1934428.  The output of echo $- showed the "e" flag.  Adding set +e fixed the issue.